# How do I remove the last six characters of every line in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have the following characters being repeated at the end of every line:

```
^[[00m
```

How can I remove them from each line using the Vim editor?

When I give the command `:%s/^[[00m//g`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Noting that the ^[ represents the ESC character, I'd take the easy way out: `%s/.....$//`, or `%s/..00m$//`, since the ESC and `[` will give you issues is you're not conversant with VIM's (or PERL's!)  regex parsing.  But yeah, that '^[' thing will get you.  put your cursor on it, notice it never touches the [ of ^[, which means it's a single character.  Something I find VERY helpful is to add the value of the char under the cursor to your statusbar, which of course I can't find.   Try putting cursor on a character and typing 'ga', it'll show you what that character is.

Answer (score 84):

You could use `:%s/.\{6}$//` to literally delete 6 characters off the end of each line.

The `:` starts ex mode which lets you execute a command. `%` is a range that specifies that this command should operate on the whole file. The `s` stands for substitute and is followed by a pattern and replace string in the format `s/pattern/replacement/`. Our pattern in this case is `.\{6}$` which means match any character (`.`) exactly 6 times (`\{6}`) followed by the end of the line (`$`) and replace it with our replacement string, which is nothing. Therefore, as I said above, this matches the last 6 characters of every line and replaces them with nothing.

Comment: Maybe you could add an explanation or reference why and how this works?

Comment: If you want to do for a selection instead of the entire file, press `ctrl+v` to do a visual selection. Then `:'<,'>s/.\{6}$//`

Answer (score 19):

I would use the global command.

Try this:

```
:g/$/norm $xxxxxx
```

or even:

```
:g/$/norm $5Xx
```

I think the key to this problem is to keep it generic and not specific to the characters you are trying to delete.  That way the technique you learn will be applicable to many other situations.

Comment: It is good to know how to remove the last # characters from every line but I think it is important to inform everyone what you are doing exactly. Something like: 
`:g/$/` (for every line)?, 
`norm` run the following command, 
`$` go to the end of the line, 
`xxxxxx` remove 6 characters. Most importantly explain the lesser known like `norm`.

Comment: By the way, the capital `X` is like `x`, but deletes backwards.

Comment: Also you don't need to use the global command at all. You can replace `:g/$/norm` with `:%norm`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming this is an ANSI escape sequence, the `^[` stands for a single `<Esc>` character. You have to enter it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) on many Windows Vim installations), followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Notice how this is then highlighted in a slightly different color, too.

Answer (score 5):

It's easy enough to replace the last six characters of every line being agnostic to what those characters are, but it leaves considerable room for error so I wouldn't recommend it. Also, if `^[` is an escape character, you're really looking for *five* characters.

#### Escape code

Using <kbd>ga</kbd> on the character `^[` you can determine whether it's an escape code, in which case the status bar would display

```
<^[>  27,  Hex 1b,  Octal 033
```

Assuming it is, you can replace everything using

```
:%s/\%x1b\[00m$//gc
```

With `\%x1b` coming from the hex value above. Note also that you have to escape the bracket (`[`) because it's a reserved character in Vim regex. `$` makes sure it occurs at the end of a line, and the `/gc` flags will make it global and confirm each replacement (you can press `a` to replace all).

#### Not escape code

It's a simple matter of escaping then. You can use either of the two below:

```
:%s/\^\[\[00m$//gc
:%s/\V^[[00m\$//gc
```

Answer (score 4):

If they are all aligning, you can do a visual-block selection and delete it then.

Otherwise, if you have a sequence unknown how to input, you can visually select it by pressing `v`, then mark and yank it `y` (per default into register `"`). Then you type `:%s/<C-R>"//g` to delete it.

Note:

- `<C-R>"` puts the content of register `"` at the cursor position.
- If you yanked it into another register, say `"ay` (yank to register `a` - the piglatin yank, as I call it) and forgot where you put it, you can look at the contents of your registers with `:reg`.
- `<C-R>` is Vim speak for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much it helped in  deleting  special character  ^@. But, later understood that Its  Ctrl+@. But, the above solution helped in copy pasting in substitute command.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine when the line is more than 5 chars long:

```
:perldo $_ = substr $_, 0, -5
```

but when the line is 5 or less chars long it does nothing.
Maybe there is a easy way in perl to delete the last 5 chars of a string, but I don't really know it:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to delete:

```
:%s/^[[00m//gc
```